# How to retrieve uploaded file in Batch-file CGI?

Tags: apache, batch-file, post, file-upload, cgi

I am making an Apache server (httpd) on Windows, and I use Batch-files as CGI-Scripts for it.

My question is, if a user uploads a file to my server via a form like this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>My Form</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV ALIGN="CENTER">
<h1>My Form</h1><br><hr><br>
<FORM ACTION="/CGI-BIN/FILE_UPLOAD.BAT" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="UPLOADFILE" PLACEHOLDER="UPLOAD A FILE">
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT">
</FORM>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

How do I *get* the file's contents? So far all I get is the file's name.

Comment: Try to use PUT method rathar than POST.

Comment: @user2956477 What would `PUT` do different?

Comment: `PUT` Isn't working either. Also, it seems that `PUT` is designed to update the current URI... Not to upload to a handler. Also, `PUT` puts the params in the URI like a `GET` request...

Comment: I still can't get any more than the file's name...

Comment: Any help? Guys?